# about the dimension of a quotient ring as a $\mathbb{C}$-vector space

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, vector-spaces, commutative-algebra, localization

what is the dimension of the following quotient ring as a $\mathbb{C}$-vector space ?

$$\mathbb{C}\left[x,\frac{1}{x-x^2}\right]/\left(x-x^3\right)$$

How to find a basis(consisted of polynomials) of this vector space?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that $(x-x^3) = \bigl((x-x^2)(x+1)\bigr) = (x+1)$ as ideals in $\mathbb C[x, \frac1{x-x^2}]$. Therefore, we have an isomorphism
$$
\mathbb C\left[x,\frac1{x-x^2}\right]/(x-x^3) = \mathbb C\left[x,\frac1{x-x^2}\right]/(x+1) \cong \mathbb C
$$
induced by $x\mapsto -1$ (and hence $\frac1{x-x^2}\mapsto -\frac12$). The dimension of your ring is therefore 1 and a basis is given by 1.

Comment: That's great! Thank you very much. But how did you find out that $(x-x^3) = (x+1)$?

Comment: Well, with $\frac1{x-x^2}$ also $\frac1{x} = \frac{1-x}{x-x^2}$ and $\frac1{1-x} = \frac{x}{x-x^2}$ are in your ring. Then I factorized $x-x^3 = x(1-x)(1+x)$ and observed that the first two factors are units.

Comment: Thanks. It is very helpful.